# Why azure webssh is not working on a linux container

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Hi I have a web app running .net web application. I just find I cannot webssh to the container anymore? It only happens to one resource group. Could you help to identify the problem?

It is NOT a custom container. (I've read this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/220501/azure-web-app-with-linux-container-ssh-login-issue) but it is for a custom container)

From the dev tool in Edge, the error is "`42["ssherror","SSH CONN ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Couldnt connect to main site container"]`"

I've tried az cli

```
az webapp ssh -n XXX -g YY
```

and

```
az webapp create-remote-connection --subscription XXXX --resource-group YY -n XXX
```

The error I got is
"`SSH endpoint unreachable, your app must be running before it can accept SSH connections.Use az webapp log tail to review the app startup logs.`"

```
If I az webapp log tail, the log is nothing about the ssh.
```

The Web App is currently running.

The Kudu site is currently running.

Comment: Is the ssh service installed and properly configured in your container image?

Comment: It is NOT a custom container, so I assume MS have openssh installed and started. 
Ssh does work in a different webapp with similar set up.

Answer (score 0):

Post the solution here, just in case someone run into the same issue.
Don't know the cause, but I solved that by turn the SSH option off and on.
Quite typical solution isn't it?
[image]